# Does the GitHub API provide a way to check if a branch is up-to-date?

Tags: github, httprequest, github-api, github-enterprise, github-api-v3

In GitHub, in the branch protection settings, you can require branches to be up to date before merging (this is possible both for both GitHub Enterprise and for public repos in free GitHub):

[image]

Then on a PR, if the branch is not up to date with the base branch, and this base branch is protected in this way, you will see the following in the UI:

[image]

Using the GitHub API, is there any way to detect if a branch is out of date relative to a base branch, or to detect if a PR is such that the head branch is out-of-date with the base branch?

I am working with a GitHub Enterprise instance, so unique features of the GitHub Enterprise API can be included in any answers.

I already looked through the [GitHub Enterprise API docs](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4) in some detail, and I didn't see a way to detect this, but it is very possible I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, this can be done by using the [compare commits API endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits#compare-two-commits).

You can make a request to this API endpoint, and then check the `behind_by` part of the JSON response. If this value is 0, the head branch is up-to-date relative to the base branch; else, the head branch is not up-to-date relative to the base branch.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do this with just `git` rather than having to query GitHub's API...